# Pencils of conic sections in the real Euclidean plane.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Consider the real Euclidean plane. My question is whether or not there exists a pencil of solely parabolas, in which at least one is non-degenerate.

If so, is there a similar statement for ellipses and hyperbolae?

Thanks!

Comment: perhaps you could define what you mean by a "pencil"? My searching only finds that term used in linear algebra to describe matrices of single-variable polynomials. While certain parabolas can be expressed as such, ellipses and hyperbolas cannot.

Comment: A pencil (dimension 2) is a set of conic sections that is generated by two linear independent symmetric bilinear forms. A pencil generated by $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ is written as $\langle \phi_1,\phi_2\rangle$. Moreover, if $A$ is the matrix of the conic associated to $\phi_1$ and matrix $A'$ to $\phi_2$, then all elements in the pencil $\langle \phi_1,\phi_2\rangle$ are given by $\lambda\phi_1+\mu\phi_2$ or, equivalently, $\lambda A + \mu A'$.

Comment: About degeneracy: a pencil has at least one and at most three degenerate elements (= conic sections). The matrix of a degenerate conic section in a pencil (using notation from previous comment) satisfies $\det(\lambda A + \mu A') =0$, for certain $\lambda, \mu\in \mathbb{R}^{*} $ and $A, A'$ the matrices of the conic sections (and thus symmetric bilinear forms) that generate the pencil.